# How can I find value (Count) in JSON data in PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I'm new to MySql queries:

Below is what I'm having issues with.

So I'm saving json_data as:
I'm using PHP json_encode to convert the array into JSON formate and store it directly in the data column.

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"abc": 123, "947": 234, "874": 123} |
| 2 | {"abc": 369, "659": 123, "523": 123} |

I just want to get the total no of users (COUNT) that have the value `123` in their Data Column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using PHP json_encode to convert the array into JSON formate and store it directly in the data column.

You may use JSON_SEARCH() function. But it searches for string-type data only. Hence for to create effective query you must store the values into your JSON as strings, not as numbers.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, data JSON)
> SELECT 1 id,  '{"abc": "123", "947": "234", "874": "123"}' data 
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, '{"abc": "369", "659": "123", "523": "123"}'
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, '{"abc": "369", "659": "456", "523": "567"}';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', '123')) AS values_amount
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | values_amount
> -: | ------------:
>  1 |             2
>  2 |             2
>  2 |          null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id
> FROM test
> WHERE JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', '123'));
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', '123')) AS values_amount
> FROM test
> HAVING values_amount;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | values_amount
> -: | ------------:
>  1 |             2
>  2 |             2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd26264118c07556eaa35039df9031d3)*

Comment: Thanks, Akina, this seems to be the optimal solution. But can you confirm that it'll only find within the value that is the text after : "" in the data column, So for example it will only find the Value of "123".

Comment: @AbhishekSharma ?? *JSON_SEARCH() function. But it searches for string-type data **only**.* Does this is not enough? Neither numeric nor special values can be searched with this function.

Comment: Yes amazing, thanks you're always spot on in MySql Question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it also by PHP
after you made your sql query, you get you object $YOUR_USER_SQL_ARRAY

```
foreach($YOUR_USER_SQL_ARRAY as $userID => $userValues){

$userValuesdecoded = json_decode($userValues)
$counter++;

foreach($userValuesdecoded as $key => $value){

if($value == 123) $counter++;

}
}
```

this way you can get the number of 123 for all users, even if there is more than "123" for each user

Comment: Is it effective if I'll have hundred and thousands of Users?

Comment: maybe not the optimal solution in this case, but it will work, and remember you are making the loop for $YOUR_USER_SQL_ARRAY, which is already in the RAM. so it will not be that bad compared to a complex SQL query